# How to automatically reinstall module in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-11

I have a setup Odoo on our local system

In Odoo 11 whenever I customized or made changes in module then I have to Reinstall the app.

Is there any other way by which I do not have to reinstall every time?

Answer (score 0):

After every change of the source code (Python code), you have to restart the Odoo service.

Changes in XML/JS/CSS files won't require a service restart, but the module has to be reinstalled.

To make this auto install every time you run the Odoo service, do as the following:

1. Create in your Module dir, a file `<module_dir>/data/<module_name>_updater.xml`

   ```
   <odoo>
       <data>
           <function model="ir.module.module" name="update_list"/>
       </data>
   </odoo>
   ```
2. Add this file to your `__manifest__.py` file.

   ```
   'data': [
       ...,
       'data/<module_name>_updater.xml',
       ...
   ],
   ```
3. Run your Odoo service with

   If you run your service by the executable python file

   ```
   /bin/odoo -u <module_name>
   ```

   If you run your service with `service odoo start`, then add this line to your `odoo.conf` file

   ```
   [options]
   update = <module_name>
   ```